# Updating a SQL record if the record data doesn't match current data

Tags: mysql, sql

**>>> About <<<**

Hello, So basically Mojang are changing the way how accounts are identified as premium accounts in Minecraft. They're now using Universal Unique Identifiers (UUID). So I have to modify my table columns to look something like this:

```
`key` , `date_joined` , `permission` , `mc_uuid` , `mc_name`
```

- key is the unique key for each record.
- date_joined is their join date.
- permission is their level of permission using integers.
- mc_uuid is their mojang uuid.
- mc_name is their minecraft in-game name.

Now mojang will allow users to change their minecraft name, however I've already stored their name into the database.

**>>> Question <<<**

So my question is how would I be able to check if the UUID of the user is the same, but if their in-game name has changed, update their name on the table all in one statement?

**Any help would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: Are you looking for sql to to change the `mc_name` field for a record? `UPDATE <table> SET mc_name=<new name> WHERE mc_uuid=<mc_uuid>;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Update statement you can write something like :

```
update table set mc_name=newmc_name where uuid=in_uuid and mc_name != newmc_name;
```

But I am not sure I understood the questions... so it might not answer what you meant...
If this is the case - can you explain better what you meant?